# Scala Class[_$1] where type _$1

Tags: scala, reflection, types, scala-2.10, jackson-modules

Right now trying to instantiate a new `JSONConverter` to register Jackson's Scala module.

```
  private def getConverter(implicit m: ClassTag[T]) = {
    new JSONConverter[T](classTag[T].runtimeClass, bucketName)
    JSONConverter.registerJacksonModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    converter
  }
```

The above code sits in a standard Scala trait that looks like `trait Writeable[T] { }`.

The problem with the above code is that Scala seems to be having a difficult time with Types. Compiler error is:

```
[error]  found   : Class[_$1] where type _$1
[error]  required: Class[T]
[error]         val converter = new JSONConverter[T](classTag[T].runtimeClass, bucketName(clientId))
[error]                                                          ^
[error] one error found
```

Anyone know the source or easy fix of this issue? Thanks!

### Update

Although `@wingedsubmariner` had an answer that allowed this to originally compile, as soon as I went to write more code the issue cascaded further. I'll show an example:

```
val o = bucketLookup(clientId).fetch(id, classTag[T].runtimeClass).withConverter(converter).withRetrier(DB.retrier).r(DB.N_READ).execute()
```

At `withConverter` the compiler throws the same error:

```
[error]  found   : com.basho.riak.client.convert.JSONConverter[T]
[error]  required: com.basho.riak.client.convert.Converter[_$1] where type _$1
[error]     val o = bucketLookup(clientId).fetch(id, classTag[T].runtimeClass).withConverter(converter).withRetrier(DB.retrier).r(DB.N_READ).execute()
```

I even tried doing the same type casting using `converter.asInstanceOf[JSONConverter[T]]` but inheritance (`JSONConverter<T> extends Converter<T>`) seems to cascade the issue. Any ideas here?

Comment: What happens when you replace `classTag[T].runtimeClass` with `classTag[T].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]` in the call to `fetch`?

Comment: @wingedsubmariner ah good call, looks like that did the trick. what a really weird issue though, that adds a lot of strange complexity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`runtimeClass` is retuning a `Class` with the wrong type parameter. Try:

```
new JSONConverter(classTag[T].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]], bucketName(clientId))
```

Comment: ugh sorry unchecked, since the issue seems to cascade when I try to actually use `JSONConverter` objects, I'll update the question